# Pandas / openpyxl - Use regex to move specific columns to a new sheet

Tags: pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

Is there a function in Pandas or openpyxl to select columns to move to a new sheet via regex? For example, I want to move all columns under headings ending in the word "Background" moved to a new sheet named "Background subtracted" and move all columns under headings starting with "delta" moved to a new sheet named "Analyzed data."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this. In my case, I selected columns ending with 'd' since those were the only ones I wanted.

```
import pandas 
path = r'yourpath'
df = pandas.read_excel(path)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine = 'openpyxl', mode = 'a')
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.endswith('d')].to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Background Subtracted')
writer.save()
```

This still leaves the columns that were moved in the original first sheet. I'm still working on deleting those columns from the first sheet.